# Missing datum only have lat long

Tags: coordinate-system, datum

I have some lat long coordinates but do not have any other information (datum, CRS etc) . I know where the place on Earth is but I cannot locate it (is a few miles off) using the coordinate numbers I have using for example Google Maps. One coordinate is (9.22618  -70.25967)

Comment: Did you try any of these?  https://epsg.io/?q=Venezuela%20kind%3ADATUM

Comment: lat=9.22,lon=-70.26 is in Venezuela; lon=9.22,lat=-70.26 is off the coast of Antarctica. Datum isn't going to make a huge difference, unless you ***know*** the collector used something other than WGS84. It's not clear how we can help you, or even what your goal is.

Comment: These could be D.MMmmm and DD.MMmmm (degrees minutes). Try mapping 9.37696667  -70.43278333 instead.

Comment: Thanks @mkennedy I did that and it works in the sense that I mapped the new points and they are in the right place. What is the name of that notation DD.MMmmm?

Comment: I'm not sure it has a well-recognized name. Possibly packed DM or DD.MMmmm. You'll also see the values separated,  DD MM.mmm which would be degrees decimal minutes.

Comment: A geodetic datum only matters if you need a precision better than 500 meters. Have you tried placing a pin on google earth to compare wgs84 coordinates of a known point?